# Itext7 PDF Form Not Editable After Writing Data

Tags: itext7

Following code i am using to write data in pdf form. The output Pdf is not editable.
I need editable pdf after updating data.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Input.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("Output.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
    //PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer,new 
    StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
    form.getField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Id[0]").setValue("12345678");
    form.getField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Name[0]").setValue("Name");
    
   form.getField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Sno[0]").setValue("11111111111");
    form.getField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Status[0]").setValue("Yes");
    form.flush();
    pdfDocument.close();
    }
```

If i use StampingProperties().useAppendMode() nothing is writing in out put pdf but is editable.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't share the PDF in question, so I have to guess. Most likely your PDF is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA form document with a usage rights signature. iText by itself has only limited XFA editing features (more than many PDF libraries but clearly less than the full set used by Adobe); apparently iText cannot properly edit your XFA. So by manipulating the PDF without append mode, you invalidate the usage rights signature and you get to see the AcroForm part which is properly edited. Due to the broken UR signature, though, you are disallowed most editing actions. ...

Comment: ... By manipulating with append mode, though, you don't break the UR signature, so you see the XFA form which is not successfully manipulated but you still have all granted editing permissions. If this guesswork is correct, you should remove both the UR signature and the XFA part and then fill-in the AcroForm form definition. For a more sound analysis please share the PDF in question.

Comment: I'm not a XFA-in-PDF expert, it's a deprecated technology after all. If I had the file, I might by trial and error find a way (nothing guaranteed!). Without it I have no idea. You might want to address iText support and sign a NDA with them, so you can share the PDF without problem. Maybe they can help.

Comment: My issue resolved by removing xfa form using api.